# Fragment's activity toolbar seems slid up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a project which has 1 activity and 3 fragments.

When I open the main activity everything looks okay, I can change to colors and styles. However, when I enter the fragment, it seems black and slid up. I can't control these. How can I get rid of this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!--    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Mail ikonu
   -->

[image: main activity]

Comment: try using `fitsSystemWindows`

Comment: Im using fitsSystemWindows=true

Comment: I added xml code of activity of fragments

Comment: remove app:layout_scrollFlags and check

Comment: Thanks it was fixed with app:layout_scrollFlags remove.